# Saving a simple blog post, should create and update methods be the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To avoid duplicating logic, should the create and update actions be the same?

ANy good examples of this?

Answer (score 1):

The `create` method is responsible for creating that simple blog post, whilst the `update` method is responsible for updating it.

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.new(params[:blog])
  if @blog.save
    flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
    redirect_to @blog
  end
end

def update
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  if @blog.update_attributes(params[:blog])
    flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
    redirect_to @blog
  end
end
```

Not much you could extract out of that besides what to do when the save succeeds / fails.

Comment: also, what if the update method fails, should I do render "new" ?

Comment: @Blankman: In the `create` method, use `save`. Both `save` and `update_attributes` in the two actions return false if the operation fails; this allows the user to correct mistakes in the form instead of redirecting them to another action. This is also why there isn't (and shouldn't be) an `else` part to the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

While `create` and `update` are similar, I don't think it worthwhile to make them literally the same.  Usually you'll want different flash messages for each.  Also, should a validation fail, on `create` it's usually best to render your `new` action, while on a failed `update`, you're more likely to want to render the `edit` action.  These little differences are typically enough so that it's simpler and more readable to have separate create and new methods.

I personally would have an `else` clause for each of `create` and `update`.  They would look like:

```
#create
else
  render :action => "new"
end

#update
else
  render :action => "edit"
end
```

The user can still see the error and correct it, but this way I don't need `create` and `update` views at all.

If you were to use `save!` or `update_attributes!` any validation error would raise an exception, which you'd have to rescue somewhere.  If you didn't rescue it, your users would receive a 500 error page every time a model failed to validate.  That's why its more conventional to use the non-! `save` and `update_attributes` methods.